# Javascript getElementByID

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, getelementbyid

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.0 and I want to change the contents of my div with Javascript, but I can't seem to "obtain" it. Here's a stripped down version to demonstrate my problem:

My Controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Index extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index.php');
    }
}
/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/index.php */
```

My View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $this->config->item('app_name'); ?> : Welcome!</title>    
<script type="text/javascript">   

function returnObjById( id )
{
    if (document.getElementById)
        var returnVar = document.getElementById(id);
    else if (document.all)
        var returnVar = document.all[id];
    else if (document.layers)
        var returnVar = document.layers[id];
    return returnVar;
}

alert('fetching moonstarttime : ' + returnObjById('moonstarttime')  );

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="moonstarttime" name="moonstarttime" >I want this</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

But when the page loads, I always get `fetching moonstarttime : null` . I've tried in both Chrome and IE, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
 function returnObjById( id )
 {
    if (document.getElementById)
        var returnVar = document.getElementById(id);
    else if (document.all)
        var returnVar = document.all[id];
    else if (document.layers)
        var returnVar = document.layers[id];
    return returnVar;
 }
 alert('fetching moonstarttime : ' + returnObjById('moonstarttime')  );
}
```

Or just place your script as is with out assing window.onload before closing the body tag.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize Javascript supported nested functions

Comment: @rlb.usa: It does, but it's irrelevant to the question. You only need the code that calls the `returnObjById` function in the `onload` handler (or after the element), you can keep the `returnObjById` function where it is if you like.

Answer (score 3):

the javascript executes before the node has loaded

Answer (score 3):

You are running the script in the header of the page, so it runs before the body has loaded. You can't reach the element because it doesn't exist yet.

Put the script after the element, or put it in a function an call the function from the onload event of the body.

Answer (score 1):

I believe was is happening is that you are attempting to retrieve the element before the DOM has been fully loaded (notice your code to select the element is before the item you want to obtain).  If you ran your code after the element in question you should get a reference to it.

As an aside, javascript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) really help do this lifting for you, and features a helper function `ready()` ([more info here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) that makes sure your code is executed only after the page has been loaded and the DOM initialized.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, your function is running before the DOM tree is built.

If you don't want to wait for the `onload` function, as it can wait a long time if your loading lots of images, for example, then you could look at using comment (5) here, which may speed up the apparent responsiveness of your page.

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/

If you put your code after the `<body>` element and put a delay you would be fine also.
So, you could use `setTimeout` as described here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp, and have something like:

`setTimeout((function returnObjectById(name) { ... })(), 30);`

which would delay the function from running for 30 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery.  It would eliminate the need for the if..elseif as well as the need for not having to test all types of browser capabilities.

in jQuery:

simply do this call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

     alert('fetching moonstarttime : ' + $('#moonstarttime')  );

  }
</script>
```